# Image does not display in header of Gridview in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I am using Visual Studio 2012, I am using a GridView with sorting functnality, sorting works perfectly but i was unable to show an image (sort image Ascending or Descending) in header section. My code is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" Width="50%" CssClass= "GridStyle-DarkGray"                  AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCreated="gv_RowCreated"    OnSorting="gv_Sorting">
     <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyID" HeaderText="ID"         SortExpression="CompanyID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Company Name"  SortExpression="CompanyName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneNo" HeaderText="Phone No" SortExpression="PhoneNo" />
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;

        return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
    }
    set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }
}
```

**Events:**

```
protected void gv_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

    if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        SortGridView(sortExpression, DESCENDING);
    }
    else
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
        SortGridView(sortExpression, ASCENDING);
    }
}

private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
{
    string conn = "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IMS;Integrated Security=True;";
    string qry = "Select * from Company";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, conn);
    DA.Fill(dt);
    gv.DataSource = dt;
    gv.DataBind();
    if (dt != null)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;
        gv.DataSource = dv;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gv_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        //Call the GetSortColumnIndex helper method to determine
        //the index of the column being sorted.

        int sortColumnIndex = GetSortColumnIndex();

        if (sortColumnIndex != -1)
        {
            // Call the AddSortImage helper method to add
            // a sort direction image to the appropriate
            // column header. 
            AddSortImage(sortColumnIndex, e.Row);
        }
    }
}

int GetSortColumnIndex()
{
    // Iterate through the Columns collection to determine the index
    // of the column being sorted.
    foreach (DataControlField field in gv.Columns)
    {
        if (field.SortExpression == gv.SortExpression)
        {
            return gv.Columns.IndexOf(field);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

// This is a helper method used to add a sort direction
// image to the header of the column being sorted.
void AddSortImage(int columnIndex, GridViewRow headerRow)
{
    // Create the sorting image based on the sort direction.
    Image sortImage = new Image();
    if (gv.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        sortImage.ImageUrl = "~/Img/asc.gif";
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/img/asc.gif";
        sortImage.AlternateText = "Ascending Order";
        lab.Text = "Ascending";
    }
    else
    {
        sortImage.ImageUrl = "~/img/desc.gif";
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/img/desc.gif";
        lab.Text = "Descending";
        sortImage.AlternateText = "Descending Order";
    }

    // Add the image to the appropriate header cell.
    headerRow.Cells[columnIndex].Controls.Add(sortImage); 
}
```

**What's wrong with my code that it does not show image in header ...?**

Comment: Use a css class in which provide your image as background and apply that css class to your `<HeaderStyle>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Add this in Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {       
        Image img = new Image();
        img.ImageUrl = "~/Contents/Images/asc.png";
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" "));
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Controls.Add(img);
    }
}
```

Change Cell index with your image cell index

Comment: I don't get any error, but when i run my program, it still don't show any image in header. image path is also correct.

Comment: At load of Page , it shows image at column index No 1. but when i sort. mean click on header for sort it does not show any sort image

Comment: I am having an issue with mine :/